# Task is not executing code properly

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, executorservice

I have a set of **tasks** that executing in **series** with an `ExecutorService`.
A `NullPointerException` is throwing the most of the times **but not always**.

All my previous tasks are requesting data from a website except this one but they all serializing data to a file through the serializeService.

Why this happens? I can't spot the source of the problem.

Tasks:

```
    ...
    Task<List<Course>> parseGradesTask = new Task<List<Course>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Course> call() {
            return studentParser.parseStudentGrades();
        }
    };

    Task<HashMap<String, String>> parseRegTask = new Task<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> call() {
            return studentParser.parseStudentRegistration();
        }
    };

    parseGradesTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        List<Course> newList = parseGradesTask.getValue();
        List<Course> newGrades = getNewlyListedCourses(newList);
        if(!newGrades.isEmpty()) {
            serializeService.serializeRecentCourses(newGrades);
            setTableViewRecent();
            notifyGrade(newGrades);
        }
        serializeService.serializeCourses(newList);
        setTableViewCourses();
    });

    parseRegTask.setOnSucceeded(e-> {
        // Exception starts from this line:
        List<Course> regList = serializeService.fetchRegisterCourseList(parseGradesTask.getValue(), parseRegTask.getValue());
        serializeService.serializeRegister(regList);
        setTableViewReg();
    });

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    // other tasks
    es.submit(() -> new Thread(parseGradesTask).start());
    es.submit(() -> new Thread(parseRegTask).start());
    es.shutdown();
```

NullPointerException on fetch method:

```
public List<Course> fetchRegisterCourseList(List<Course> courseList, HashMap<String, String> courseIdList) {
    List<Course> courseRegList = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator it = courseIdList.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        // NullPointerException on this line:
        courseRegList.addAll(courseList.stream().filter(course ->
                course.getCourseId().equals(pair.getKey()) && course.getCourseTitle().equals(pair.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
    return courseRegList;
}
```

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.example.test.service.Impl.SerializeServiceImpl.fetchRegisterCourseList(SerializeServiceImpl.java:100)
>     at
>   com.example.test.controller.MainController.lambda$syncCourses$4(MainController.java:450)

Comment: So which line is line 100?

Comment: its on the fetch method, i have a comment there.

Comment: What debugging attempts have you made? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Whenever i do step-by-step debugging i do not get any exceptions and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `parseRegTask` finishes before `parseGradesTask`, then in the handler for `parseRegTask`, `parseGradesTask.getValue()` will return `null`. Of course, this value is passed as `courseList` to `fetchRegisterCourseList`, and `courseList.stream()` will throw a `NullPointerException`. Since each task is run in its own thread, this is clearly possible.

I think you are intending to run both tasks on the single thread provided by the executor. To do this you need

```
es.submit(parseGradesTask);
es.submit(parseRegTask);
```

Comment: Thank you so much mr James!! For once more!

Comment: I think i have found a bug in IntelliJ but i'm not sure. When i run my application through IntelliJ the last Task (parseRegTask) is always hanging BUT when i package the jar and run it its working fine. Do you have any idea what is happening?